# Converting from Vmware to Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, vmware-workstation

I am trying to convert a VMWare Workstation Player to Hyper-V, and I see most posts using the Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter.

However my VMs have multiple VMDK files that comprises each. Can I still use that software to convert to a single VHDX file, or it will need to output to multiple VHDX files?

If I can clarify the best aproach to converting multiple VMDK files to Hyper-V is all I am after.

Thanks all

Comment: The following is a very complete document including a powershell method when the GUI does not handle the complete job.   https://askme4tech.com/how-convert-vmware-virtual-machine-hyper-v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use StarWind V2V converter to convert VMs between hypervisors. You can choose VMDKs you want to convert, it could be either one or many VMDKs to convert.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter

Comment: Thank you, this was the best solution for me